# ASP.NET application does not retrieve symbols (apostrophe's etc) properly?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have built an ASP.NET website with a back-end database in MS SQL Server 2008.

Everything is working fine in terms of using the web app to insert and modifying records from the database.

The only problem I am having is that if any of text boxes contain any symbols such as (apostrophe, speech marks etc) - they are displayed as special characters

[image]

When I check SQL Server Management Studio, it displays it correctly as "D'Aubney", then why does it change it to special characters when sending the data back to ASP website text boxes.

The Edit page is using this code to retrieve sessions into text boxes:

```
ContactName.Text = Session("ContactName")
```

I tried looking for various solutions online but this problem is too complicated for me.

Comment: Anything assigned to the `Text` property is automatically HTML Encoded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx

Comment: What does the value look like in Session("ContactName") ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the above

```
   public String CleanInput(string strIn)
    {
        return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strIn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Web to your project and use the following:

```
Dim output As String = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(yourText)
```

[MSDN Documentation for HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx)